# Assign accessibility identifiers to urls in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

How can we assign the unique accessibility identifiers to the urls in UITextView? In the accessibility inspector, I am able to see the urls as separate elements but not able to set the accessibility identifiers for them which are needed for automation testing.

[image]

Comment: Post the code you have already tried. You will get a much better response that way.

Comment: @RobC I have just taken the UITextView and accessibility is enabled for that. iOS automatically handles the accessibility for links within through link rotor.